# Mysql circular query from given row

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table containing `user_id` , `skill`.

```
user_id  skill
1         foo
1         bar
2         foo
3         bar
```

lets say a job is given to `user 1` based on his ***bar*** skill.

If a new offer received that needs **bar skill** too, I want to delegate it to **next** user having that skill.

If no qualified user found then query from top of the table to find a user with that skill.

There is another table named jobs that records all jobs history.its columns are id, user_id, skill, and timestamps

Comment: It means according to your code when the offer received the job will allocated to the user with id : 3 for skill bar. is it you want ?

Comment: yes. and if there were no user 3 in table , then the job should be allocated to next user that is user 1.

Comment: Don't think it's possible with a single query. You would need to do one query to find the next user with bar skill who isn't the current user, and then depending on the result a second query to get the next user after the current user. What have you tried? It's just two simple queries.

Comment: oh, I was hope there would be a single query to do that.nevertheless,I can check the first query using PHP. could you provide me a pure SQL query(s) return the  ultimate result without integrating PHP?

Comment: I would like to know how you are confirming that user has been allocated to the respective job with the desired skill ? I mean do you have separate table for that ?

Comment: yes.that's right. there is another table named *jobs* that records all jobs history.its columns are `id`, `user_id`, `skill`, and timestamps

Comment: Of course it's possible with a single query :-)

Comment: @Strawberry would you please write that single query ?

Answer (score 1):

This is incomplete, but should provide some food for thought...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_skill;

CREATE TABLE user_skill
(user_id  INT NOT NULL
,skill_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(user_id,skill_id)
);

INSERT INTO user_skill VALUES
(1,101),
(1,102),
(2,101),
(3,103);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jobs;

CREATE TABLE jobs
(job_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,skill_id INT NOT NULL
,assigned_to INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO jobs VALUES
(1001,101,1),
(1002,103,NULL),
(1003,102,NULL),
(1004,101,NULL);

UPDATE jobs x 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT u.*
            , us.skill_id
            , unassigned.job_id
         FROM user u 
         JOIN user_skill us 
           ON us.user_id = u.user_id 
         LEFT 
         JOIN jobs assigned  
           ON assigned.assigned_to = u.user_id 
         JOIN jobs unassigned 
           ON unassigned.skill_id = us.skill_id 
        WHERE unassigned.assigned_to IS NULL 
        ORDER 
           BY assigned.job_id IS NULL DESC
            , assigned.job_id DESC LIMIT 1
     ) y
    ON y.skill_id = x.skill_id
   AND y.job_id = x.job_id
   SET x.assigned_to = y.user_id;
```

Comment: thanks, it seems a bit complex for me. i would try it